# Displaying pages without ellipses in the pagination control of a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables JS with Bootstrap, I am running into an issue where there is a workaround but it is not the nicest.

The issue: my table contains more than 4k records

If the person who is working on the table needs to work from record 200 to 300 and for easibility, he needs to see 10 records in a page, then he can click on 5 on the page number, and then on 6, then on 7 and all the way to page 20. (I know the work around will be to display 100 records and just click on page 3 to start from 200, however as I mentioned due to their job it is easier for them to see no more than 10-20 records per page).

The image below shows that I am unable to go other pages other than first,last, next or previous once I reach page 5

Is there any settings where I can say display all the pages?

This table is processed server side, and I have added the option:

```
'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/pagination/ellipses.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/pagination/select.js"></script>

j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('#sharkTankTable').dataTable({
        'aoColumns': aoColumns,
        'sPaginationType': 'listbox',
        // 'pageLength': 10,
        // // 'sPaginationType': 'ellipses',
        // 'iShowPages': 10,
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        // 'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
        'sDom': 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        'bFilter': true,
        'tableTools':{"sSwfPath": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"},
        'sAjaxSource': 'fakeUrl',
        'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### PROBLEM

Latest version of DataTables 1.10.7 does not have this ability by default.

There are [pagination plug-ins](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/) that provide additional functionality. One of them, [Ellipses](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/ellipses), has `iShowPages` option allowing to define number of pages to display in pagination control.

However per [@davidkonrad's note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633288/displaying-all-pages-from-the-pagination-of-a-datatable/30633820#comment49350727_30633820), Ellipses plug-in doesn't fully support DataTables 1.10, i.e. doesn't show currently selected page and disabled state of some buttons.

#### SOLUTION

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850489/3549014) or [jQuery DataTables – Pagination without ellipses](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-pagination-without-ellipses/) for a better solution.

Comment: I hate to say it - but the ellipses pagination plugin is deprecated. The functionality is now natively supported by dataTables, and ellipsis does not work well with 1.10.x as your fiddle shows (active page is not highlighted, prev / next buttons does not work at all) - but it is a good answer for dataTables 1.9.x.

Comment: @davidkonrad, you're right but only partially. Although plug-in doesn't highlight active page, all buttons work for me. I have updated JSFiddle to highlight the active page. Plug-in still works for 1.10 which is why it's included in 1.10 branch (see CDN link in the post which has `1.10.7`) and is listed on DataTables website in plug-in section, otherwise it would be removed. Also, OP needed to display more than 3 pages between ellipses which DataTables cannot do natively, but Ellipses plug-in can with extra option `iShowPages`.

Comment: @Manza, what version of the DataTables you're using? My examples are based on 1.10, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much, i am using the latest one: 1.10.7 it is very weird because my table definition is really long i realized that I had twice 'sPaginationType': defined, however, after deleting the second one if I left 'sPaginationType': 'listbox', the whole table disappears and the console shows the error: in jquery: TypeError: c is undefined
 

f=a.aanFeatures;e||c.fnInit(a,b

Comment: @Manza, see how [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw31vg4y/5/) is structured and how `iShowPages` controls how many pages to display in pagination control. `sPaginationType` is option name for older DataTables 1.9, but code using DataTables 1.10 should use `pagingType`.

Comment: As I was using this: var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); I have to open the file //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/pagination/select.js and modify this line: $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.listbox to j$.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.listbox
and then save it and use this new file instead of the cdn

Comment: @Manza, you must include http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f3e99a6c02/pagination/select.js in order to use `pagingType : 'listbox" `and also some cleaining is nessecary, but then it works with 1.10.7 too -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ybbmagqx/**

Comment: @davidkonrad, extra cleaning is not necessary, you're using older 1.10.0 version of DataTables in your example and older `select.js` as well, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30668366/3549014) showing Select extension working correctly. As of now correct URL is http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/pagination/select.js.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, OK - yes, my std 1.10.x demo is not using latest version, should really correct that.  I was also baffled i could not find select.js under plugins, only in historic branches, but must have missed that, good answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem before , you can just hide the element using css on the top of your page , just like this :

```
 .ellipsis {
        display: none;
    }
```