# Desired page in pagination with Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using Tabulator, I need to add input box that takes you to a desired page.
If you have 10 pages and you want to go to page 9 you would just input 9 and hit enter.
This feature is available in DataTables here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666969/desired-page-in-pagination-with-datatables/30668366#30668366)
so how to do this with Tabulator? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/page#manage

You would need to use the `table.setPage(x)` function where table is your Tabulator instance and x is the page number you want to go to.

So here is an example of what the event listener function would look like on one of your elements.

```
function pageListener(event){
  if (isNaN(event.target.value)){
    // We don't want anything that isn't a number.
    return;
  }
  // Assuming that 'table' is a variable containing the
  // Tabulator instance
  table.setPage(Number(event.target.value));
}
```

And here is a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/fewqhuar/1/

Comment: is there a way to show the page number inside the input box as placeholder until user click in the box

Comment: table.getPage() gives you the current page number. So use that to find the number and set the input placeholder/value to that number.

Comment: Hi i tried this but the placeholder value doesn't get updated when clicking "next, prev first, last". should i post a new question:<input id="currentPage"/>                                     document.getElementById("currentPage").placeholder = tabulator_table.getPage();

Comment: Yes, you should post a new question.  I will see if I can get you an answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @nrayburn-tech answer, I modified somethings to make the input box displayed in the tabulator footer.

```
//CSS
         #test  {
                color:black;
                text-align: center;
                position:center;
            }
     .jumpTo{
                width:30px;
                height:10px;
            }
//JS
       $(".tabulator-footer").append("<div id='test'><input class='jumpTo' title='insert number to jump to a page'></input></div>");
                document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                    if (isNaN(event.target.value)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    tabulator_table.setPage(Number(event.target.value));
                })
```

Thank you a lot