# How to show and update current page number in an input box palceholder Using Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to show the current page number in an input box as a place holder the issue is I can't figure out how to update the value when users go to another page. 
Here is what I tried:

```
    <input id="currentPage"/>
 document.getElementById("currentPage").placeholder = tabulator_table.getPage();
```

Here is the first part of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503969/desired-page-in-pagination-with-tabulator)
Here is [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/fewqhuar/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `pageLoaded` callback on the table instance.

When creating the table, you need to add a property for `pageLoaded` as a function with a parameter for the page number.  This callback is triggered each time the page is loaded.

Here is a working example, https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/w68d75Lq/1/.

So you would do something like this, where `#table` is the element id for the table and `input` is a reference to your input element where you keep the page number value.

```
  new Tabulator('#table', {
    ...tableOptions,
    pageLoaded: (pageNumber) => {
      input.value = pageNumber
    }
  });
```

Comment: can i do it like this:  document.getElementById("currentPage").placeholder = tabulator_table.pageLoaded(pageNumber) <input id='currentPage' />the first approach is not working maybe because i have more than one input tag.    var tabulator_table = new Tabulator("#example", {
                height: "235px",
                layout: "fitColumns",
                pagination: "local",
                paginationSize: 15,
                paginationButtonCount: 0,
                pageLoaded: (pageNumber) => {
                    input.value = pageNumber
                },columns[] });

Comment: In the example I did, ‘input’ was a variable containing the html element. So you need to adjust it to your specific element. Which in this case, looks like it would be document.getElementById(‘currentPage’).

Comment: hi many thanks for all the help:    pageLoaded: (pageNumber) => {
                            document.getElementById('currentPage').value = pageNumber
                        },

Comment: And yes, you can use placeholder instead of value.