# How to remove ellipsis in Jquery DataTables pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery DataTables(Datatables.net) with my grid. Suppose I have 45 pages in my grid in total hence currently default pagination with 'full_numbers' showing following buttons:

*First,Last,1,2,3,4,5,...,45,Next,Last*

Now when I click on 5th page button, pagination shows buttons this way:

*First,Previous,1,...,4,5,6,...,45,Next,Last*

I don't want those ellipses, what I want is when user clicks on 5th page, I want to show next 3 pages along with 1 previous page like this:

*First,Previous,4,5,6,7,8,Next,Last*

So ultimately I want to remove ellipses and show previous page number, current page number and next n page numbers in this format:

*First,Previous,{previous page},{current page},{next 3 pages},Next,Last*

Is there any way to make it possible in DataTables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying all pages from the pagination of a datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633288/displaying-all-pages-from-the-pagination-of-a-datatable)

Comment: That example still showing ellipsis which I don't want at all. My expectations are different.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, I think there is a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### PROBLEM

Latest version of DataTables 1.10.7 does not have this ability by default.

There are [pagination plug-ins](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/) that provide additional functionality, but unfortunately none of them provide this functionality.

#### SOLUTION

We have created pagination plug-ins "Full Numbers – No Ellipses" and "Simple Numbers – No Ellipses" to overcome this problem and display pagination control without ellipses.

- "Full Numbers – No Ellipses" plug-in behaves similarly to pagination option `'pagingType': 'full_numbers'` but excludes ellipses.
- "Simple Numbers – No Ellipses" plug-in behaves similarly to pagination option `'pagingType': 'simple_numbers'` but excludes ellipses also.

#### DEMO

See [example of Full Numbers – No Ellipses plug-in](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-pagination-without-ellipses/) for demonstration and to download both plug-ins.

#### HOW TO USE

To use "Simple Numbers – No Ellipses" plug-in:

- download [simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/Plugins/master/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js)
- include it after `jquery.dataTables.min.js`
- use `'pagingType': 'simple_numbers_no_ellipses'` initialization option.

To use "Full Numbers – No Ellipses" plug-in:

- download [full_numbers_no_ellipses.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/Plugins/master/pagination/full_numbers_no_ellipses.js)
- include it after `jquery.dataTables.min.js`
- use `'pagingType': 'full_numbers_no_ellipses'` initialization option.

For example:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="full_numbers_no_ellipses.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            'pagingType': 'full_numbers_no_ellipses'
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot! Is there any documentation available with all options of this plugin?

Comment: There are no options at the moment, however you can see how `full_numbers_no_ellipses.js` is written and modify according to your needs, i.e. to display `X` number of previous pages and `Y` number of next pages.

Comment: There is a typo in simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js, it contains a plugin called full_numbers_no_ellipses when it should be called simple_numbers_no_ellipses.

Comment: Working on a legacy project and had to use jquery. The links are broken, you can find the source here: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/full_numbers_no_ellipses