# Datatable's pagination plugin shows last index page number

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

Following is my pagination code using dataTable plugin of jQuery.
This code yields an extra page number in the end.

```
 $('#example').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    fnCreatedRow: function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $("#example").find("td").addClass("ellipsis");
        var progressId = "#progressbar" + iDataIndex;
        $(progressId).progressbar({
            value: 37
        });

    },

    dom: '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [[2, "asc"]],
    language: {
    "emptyTable": "<div class='TabletextRow' style='margin-left:6% !important'><div class='Icon-Nodata'></div> <div class='TableNodataText' style='margin-top:1% !important'> No Records Found.</div>", 
        "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
        "aria": {
            "sortascending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
            "sortdescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
        },
        "paginate": {
            "first": "First",
            "last": "Last",
            "next": ">>",
            "previous": "<<"
        },
    }
```

For. eg: We have 120 records and each page show 10 records. But we can see 12th page index in the UI i.e last page index. How I can remove that?

[image]

Comment: page twelve should contain items # 110-119...

Comment: Yes, it contains, but I don't want to show 12 on UI. How i can achieve that?

Comment: each button has attribs/classes you can hit in css, so display:none; a selector pointing to that button.

Comment: I can do that, but that is not feasible solution. When you are at page 12, 1st index page is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

> **CAUSE**

If you have `120` records, there will be page `12` that will contain records from `111` through `120`.

Apparently you have applied custom styling to the pagination. In the default style between page `5` and `12` there is also ellipsis (`...`) element. Most likely your CSS rules hide this element.

[image: Default pagination control]

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7gLzzwj/1/) for code and demonstration.

> **SOLUTION**

Correct your CSS rules to show ellipsis (`...`) characters.

Alternatively, see [my answer on how to remove ellipses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850489/3549014) or article [jQuery DataTables – Pagination without ellipses](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-pagination-without-ellipses/).